# Xcode: How do I put this into a loop?

Tags: objective-c, variables, loops

I am fairly new to xcode and trying to make my code more efficient. I have the code below and I want to put the repeated lines at the end into a loop (there are many more items in the array). I am sure it's very simple but I can't figure out how to evaluate the variables within the loop. I am obviously asking Google the wrong question too as it isn't helping!

```
GlossaryDetailViewController *dController = segue.destinationViewController;
glossaryDict = glossaryArray [indexPath.row];
dController.detailLabelText = [glossaryDict objectForKey:@"Explanation"];
dController.detailTitle = [glossaryDict objectForKey:@"Term"];
NSMutableArray *labelArray;
labelArray = [glossaryDict objectForKey:@"Label"];
dController.labelString0 = labelArray[0];
dController.labelString1 = labelArray[1];
```

I know how to create the loop ie for(int i=0;i

Any pointers much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to assign `dController.labelString0` in the first iteration of the loop and `dController.labelString1` in the second iteration? I don't think it can be done... at least not in a way that is even vaguely "more efficient" than what you have now. You would have to make `dController.labelString` an array...

Comment: do you wnat to fill all `labelStringXX` with loops? how many do dController has?

Comment: I agree with Floris.... +1 to Floris

Comment: Thanks Anoop! I think OP needs to edit the question some more...

Comment: @userXXXXX : Don't dump a question and go for a walk. You should respond for questions/clarifications etc

Comment: Thanks Floris, an array is what I should be using. As I say I am new to this so I don't always think of the most efficient method. Apologies for not responding immediately I lost wifi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to automate these :

```
dController.labelString0 = labelArray[0];
dController.labelString1 = labelArray[1];
dController.labelStringxx=labelArray[xx];
```

Then you have two ways:

Either **Use Arrays** for all the individual properties of `GlossaryDetailViewController`

```
for(NSInteger i=1; i<labelArray.count; i++){
    dController.labelString[i]=labelArray[i];
}
```

Or, **use Key Value Coding** (if you are restricted not to change the class):

```
for (NSInteger i=1; ;i++) { //still here you need to put 1 
    NSString *propertyName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"labelString%d",i];
    if([dController respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(propertyName)]){
        [dController setValue:labelArray[i] forKey:propertyName];
    }
    else break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes this makes sense to what I want to do. The array loop will work. :)

Comment: @user157733: even kvc will work if you dont want to make them array, as it may be someone others class, and you are not supposed to touch that.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly from your question, but I think you want something like this

```
for (NSString *str in labelArray){
//do stuff with str
NSLog(@"%@", str);
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < [labelArray count]; i++){
dController.labelString[i] = labelArray[i];
}
```

To do the second option, you would have to do what @Floris said, and put the `labelStrings` into an array.

Comment: **NO WAY.** Incorrect

Comment: @AnoopVaidya ? I can't tell what he's asking for, but that's what it looked like. What's so incorrect about my answer?

Comment: Read the comment in question. If you are not sure, they you should ask, as even I and Floris where not sure about the requirement. so commented with question. And Floris idea is good.

Comment: Different iterations should assign to a different .labelString (with a number after the name)...

Comment: Now you go with some sort of answer, Still he does not have labelString as NSArray/NSMutbleArray.

Comment: Well he would have to do that himself, there's no way I could tell him since I don't know how many labelStrings he has.