# Using string for variable name iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, cllocation

I got some trouble to find how to use a string for my CLLocationCoordinate2D name variable.
In my code I got 90 location :

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location1;
...
CLLocationCoordinate2D location90;
```

And I would like to call this method :

```
locationConverToImage = [myMapView convertCoordinate:location1 toPointToView:drawView];
```

in a for loop like this :

```
for (int i=1; i<=90; i++) {
    NSString *newCoord = @"location";
    [newCoord stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
    locationConverToImage = [myMapView convertCoordinate:newCoord toPointToView:drawView];
}
```

But the problem is that I can't use string for the variable name.
How can I do ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you using an array?

Comment: OR KVC will also do, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825602/xcode-how-do-i-put-this-into-a-loop/15826047#15826047)

Comment: try saving your location data in array. P.S. My goodness, have you really created 90 variables in you interface list? :)

Comment: This is a first iteration, 'cause I can't find how to use a kmlParser for my mapview.

Answer (score 1):

you could have used arrays, but for your question this is my answer:

```
for (int i=1; i<=90; i++) {
        NSString *newCoord = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"location%d", i];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = (CLLocationCoordinate2D)[self valueForKey:newCoord];
        locationConverToImage = [myMapView convertCoordinate:coordinate toPointToView:drawView];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using `array`

Create your array with `CLLocation` objects since you can't add `CLLocationCoordinate2D` directly to an `Array`. See the code below

```
NSMutableArray *locations=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(int i=1;i<=90;i++){
       CLLocation *loc=[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:LAT longitude:LNG];
       [locations addObject:loc];
    }
```

Then

```
for(CLLocation *loc locations){
  locationConverToImage = [myMapView convertCoordinate:loc.coordinate toPointToView:drawView];

}
```

Comment: How can I use LAT and LNG in the first loop ?
I tried NSArray *longt = @[longitude1,...,longitude90];
But not working, because it's not an object. :/

Comment: You must be getting `LAT` and `LNG` from somewhere ? And I have mentioned that `CLLocationCoordinate2D ` are not object use `CLLocation` instead..

Comment: you cannot save non-object instances in any objc container class (like NSArray). To save CLLocation in NSArray, you should use CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = kCLLocationCoordinate2DInvalid;
  NSValue *val = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&loc objCType:@encode(CLLocation)];
  NSArray *array = @[ val ];
  CLLocationCoordinate2D locExtracted;
  [val getValue:&locExtracted];

Comment: I wrote them in the code like this : CLLocationCoordinate2D location1;
    location1.latitude=2.399483;
    location1.longitude=48.800983;